# Definite integral - working rules

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the definite integral given below.

$
I = \int_{0}^\pi \frac{1}{cos^2x + 4sin^2x} dx
$

Shown below is the plot of the integrand function (as shown on wolfram alpha). It doesn't show any discontinuity in$[0,\pi]$ interval. The correct answer here is $\pi/2$. However, I am getting different answers when I take different approaches (summarized below). I am looking for the correct way to solve such problems.

[image: plot of integral function]

**Common part of the solution**

On simplifying the integrand further, we get
$
I = \int_{0}^\pi \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx
$. This modified integrand does seem to have a discontinuity at $\pi/2$. However, I am not sure about this, as the plot of this modified integrand, as shown on wolfram alpha, is the same as that of the original integrand.

**First approach**

Try to find the indefinite integral $F(x)$ = $\int \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx$.

Put $tanx = t$. On solving we get,

$F(t)$ = $\int \frac{dt}{1 + 4t^2} dt$ =  $\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{dt}{(\frac{1}{2})^2 + t^2} dt$  =   $\frac{1}{2} arctan(2t) + C$.

Hence $F(x)$ = $\frac{1}{2} arctan(2tanx) + C$

Now $I = [F(x)] \Big|_0^\pi$ = $[\frac{1}{2} arctan(2tanx)] \Big|_0^\pi$ = $0$

If I understand right, this approach is incorrect as $tanx$ is not defined at $\pi/2$ (which is in the interval $[0,\pi]$).

**Second approach**

As the integrand seems to have a discontinuity at $\pi/2$, break the given interval.

$I$ = $\lim_{l \to \frac{\pi-}{2}}$ $\int_{0}^l \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx$ + $\lim_{m \to \frac{\pi+}{2}}$ $\int_{m}^\pi \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx$

Hence,

$I$ = $\lim_{l \to \frac{\pi-}{2}}$ $[\frac{1}{2} arctan(2tanx)] \Big|_0^l$ + $\lim_{m \to \frac{\pi+}{2}}$ $[\frac{1}{2} arctan(2tanx)] \Big|_m^\pi$

on solving,

$I = \frac{1}{2}[arctan(+\infty) - arctan(0)] + \frac{1}{2}[arctan(0) - arctan(-\infty)]$

$ = \frac{1}{2}[\frac{\pi}{2} - 0] + \frac{1}{2}[0 - \frac{\pi}{2}] = 0$

So this approach also seems incorrect.

**Third approach**

Using property $\int_{0}^{2a} f(x)dx = 2 \int_{0}^a f(x)dx$, when  $f(2a-x) = f(x)$

We get $I = 2 \int_{0}^\frac{\pi-}{2} \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx = [arctan(2tanx)] \Big|_0^\frac{\pi-}{2} = [arctan(-\infty) - arctan(0)] = \pi/2$

This approach seems to be giving the correct answer

**Fourth approach**

This builds on top of the third approach. Divide the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ further into $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and modify the second integrand as shown below.

$I$ = $\int_{0}^\pi \frac{1}{cos^2x + 4sin^2x} dx$ = $2\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{cos^2x + 4sin^2x} dx$

Hence,
$I$ = $2[\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{1}{cos^2x + 4sin^2x} dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{cos^2x + 4sin^2x} dx]$

$ = 2[\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{sec^2x}{1 + 4tan^2x} dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{-cosec^2x}{cot^2x + 4} dx]$

None of the integrands in the above expression has any discontinuity in their respective intervals. On solving it, we get $\pi/2$ as the answer. The textbook which I am following takes this approach.

I have the following three questions.

**Questions**

1. As far as I understand, the original integrand does not have any discontinuity in the interval $[0,\pi]$. However, the modified integrands-the ones involving $tanx$ and $cotx$ terms-do have discontinuities at $\pi/2$ and $0$ respectively. Is this understanding correct?
2. Why did the third approach work while the second one fail despite both seemingly attempting to take care of the discontinuity at $\pi/2$ by breaking the interval into subintervals?
3. Are there any general working rules to keep in mind while solving such problems?

**P.S.** I am not a formal student. Trying to self-learn basic concepts. I apologize if I may be missing something quite basic or if this question does not appear well researched.

Comment: Your second approach works. $\lim_{x\to \infty} \arctan(-x)=-\pi/2$, therefore
$$I= \frac{1}{2}[\frac{\pi}{2} - 0] + \frac{1}{2}[0 \color{red}{+} \frac{\pi}{2}] = 0.$$

Comment: @projectilemotion. I suspect a typo in your comment

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh yes, you're right. I copied the TeX from the OP's question, and forgot to edit the final result. $0$ should be replaced by $\pi/2$.

Comment: Spot on! I made a (conceptual) mistake of taking limx→∞arctan(−x) as +π/2.

Comment: Would you be able to confirm this? - "As far as I understand, the original integrand does not have any discontinuity in the interval [0,π]. However, the modified integrands-the ones involving tanx and cotx terms-do have discontinuities at π/2 and 0 respectively. Is this understanding correct?"

Comment: Without any calculation, it must be greater than $0$ since the integrand is always positive. Now, it must be greater than $\frac \pi 4$ since $\frac 1 4$ is the minimum value of the integrand and smaller than $\pi$ since $1$  is the maximum value of it.